# d3 fitSize doesn't fit the extent as expected using a geojson polygon

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis

I'm using D3 to draw geo data on top of a static map.

Before drawing the data, I'm using d3's `fitSize` method to set the projection so that the bounds of the map (as spherical lat lng pairs) fit the full extent of the canvas.

```
const size = {
  width: 1048,
  height: 447
};

const bounds = [
  -13.098400070906848,
  51.44391918744,
  17.18913007090731,
  42.66553377959798
];

const geojson = turf.bboxPolygon([bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2], bounds[3]])

const projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([size.width, size.height], geojson);

d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
```

In this example, the projection doesn't fit the extent, the scale is off by a large margin.

I should note that I get the bounds from the map beforehand so the issue shouldn't be due to a proportions difference between the canvas size and the bounds.

[I've put together an example here where the projection doesn't fit.](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-snow-nuc67?file=/src/App.js) It shows where the projection draws the bounds compared to the extent.

As you can see in the logs, the ratios of the bounds dimensions and the canvas dimensions are almost identical, meaning that we should be able to scale the bounds to the full extent of the canvas.

I'm confused as to why that is and how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of `turf.bboxPolygon`? BBox is usually an object like `{x: ..., y: ..., width: ..., height...}`. Is it correct in your case?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Thanks for dropping in! `turf.bboxPolygon` takes an array of coordinates (the [w, s, e, n] bounds of the map) and turns it into a geojson polygon that I can pass to d3. I think it's correct.

Comment: So I suppose your problem is solved now?

Comment: No, it's still intact. Why?

Comment: Can you print bbox to console? What do you see?

Comment: Sure, here is what I see. ```{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-13.098400070906848,51.44391918744],[17.18913007090731,51.44391918744],[17.18913007090731,42.66553377959798],[-13.098400070906848,42.66553377959798],[-13.098400070906848,51.44391918744]]]}}```

Comment: I suppose bbox should be of type SCFRect (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGRect): `{x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number}`... Try to replace your bbox with a valid SVGRect. Does it help?

Comment: Hmm, no. My example might be misleading, fitSize [expects a geojson object](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_fitSize), not a bbox, I've edited the example.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I think I've found the issue! Your question made me look at passing different geojson feature types to the method, like a `lineString` of the diagonal of the bbox and i'm getting what I was expecting now. This is strange. Thanks for your help!